# Minimalistic nyc (istanbul) javascript coverage not working for es-modules (ESM)

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, istanbul, nyc

Trying to figure out why I get no coverage out of `nyc` whatsovever, I ended up with a file single file `./x.js` that only contains

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict'
console.log('======= starting tests =======');
```

In `package.json` I have

```json
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "test": "nyc ./x.js",
  }
  ...
```

and when I run `npm run test` I get the following

- console log from the one-liner
- a html coverage report as requested in the config (see below), yet the line is not market as covered
- despite configuring a cache directory, it stays empty which seems to indicate that on-the-fly instrumentation is not done.

From all the examples on net I assumed that instrumentation is done on the fly and that `nyc instrument` is rather for special uses cases. Can anyone provide some inside what is going on and what not? Here is (one of the gazillion versions of) the config I tried:

```json
{
  "cache": true,
  "cache-dir": "./kkk",
  "instrument": true,
  "extension": [
    ".ts",
    ".js"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/x.js"
  ],
  "reporter": [
      "html"
  ],
  "all": true
}
```

I start getting coverage output when **not** using `"type": "module"` in my `package.json`.

**Versions**:

- node: v16.13.2
- nyc: 15.1.0

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that `nyc` in fact cannot load es-modules (ESM) on the fly. A possible solution could have been

```
npm i -D @istanbuljs/esm-loader-hook
NODE_OPTIONS='--experimental-loader @istanbuljs/esm-loader-hook' ./node_modules/.bin/nyc ..more options.. ./x.js
```

according to [this github repository](https://github.com/istanbuljs/esm-loader-hook). Yet, this did not work for me, likely because my node version (16.13.2) is too new, as promised on that site.

The above link further points to [c8](https://github.com/bcoe/c8#readme) as a solution. Some background can be found on the [c8 developer's blog](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/rethinking-javascript-test-coverage-5726fb272949). Bottom line: es-modules were difficult to implement for `istanbul`, so use a new `node` feature to collect coverage data and "just" convert this to human readable form: c8.

Works for me, given the example file in the question,

```
./node_modules/.bin/c8 node ./x.js
```

produces the expected coverage output. Further I noticed that when a `.js` file is included that was produced by the typescript compiler with `"sourceMap": true`, the coverage nicely shows the `.ts` file.